# Nix coding pattern: merging two conditional lists created with mkIf

Tags: nix, nixos

When given two lists each of which are conditional on basis of `mkIf`, how to merge those two lists (akin to `mkMerge` for sets)?
I have run into the following pattern several times now and I cannot seem to find documentation explaining how to idiomatically solve this.

Say you're starting out with this snippet:

```hs
someConfigValue = mkIf (cfg.condition1) [ "some value 1" ];
```

Then you add another conditional value:

```hs
someConfigValue = [
  (mkIf (cfg.condition1) [ "some value 1" ])
  (mkIf (cfg.condition2) [ "some value 2" ])
];
```

In the specific case at hand (trying to pass this to `systemd.services.<name>.LoadCredential`) I get the following error since the internal representation of the two `mkIf` values are sets:

```
error: cannot coerce a set to a string
```

Using `mkMerge` does not seem to work either (since it takes a list of sets and merges those sets).
I could replace the `mkIf`s with `optionals` and then concatenate the lists using `++`, but that's dumping all the module logic, so I'm not sure whether that's the right choice here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ordinarily, I would use `optionals` for something like this.

If you really want to make it mergable, I think you can instead put `whateverService.serviceConfig.LoadCredentials = [ "cred 1" ];` on one side of a merge and `whateverService.serviceConfig.LoadCredentials = [ "cred 2" ];` on the other side, and the standard merging logic will put them in the same list.

This more or less results in just pushing `someConfigValue` in one level:

```
config = mkMerge [
  (mkIf (cfg.condition1) { someConfigValue = [ "some value 1" ]; })
  (mkIf (cfg.condition2) { someConfigValue = [ "some value 2" ]; })
];
```

Which is more or less how I tend to see `mkIf` used: It predicates whole sections of config at the top level, rather than individual values inside of config. Individual values tend to use things like `optionals` or `optionalString`.